# Smb network delays

Tags: android, networking

I suspect this is a network issue rather than SMB but I'm not a networking expert so any help would be appreciated.

I have just finished developing an Android app for bridge clubs to send scores recorded at table to a central (Windows) scoring computer and report results back to the players. The app communicates with the PC by reading and writing files using SMB.

At home, using my domestic WiFi, I can fetch the files I need in less than 4 seconds, which is acceptable performance. However, using the bridge club's router introduces a 21 second delay reading a file.
On investigation, it's the new SmbFileInputStream call that takes 21 seconds to return. File name parameter is of the form smb://user:password@server/path.

I am using the same Android device and server PC. The only difference is the router, which is a Netgear N300 wireless ADSL+.

Any ideas? What, if anything, should I be looking for in the router settings?

Answer (score 0):

SMB isn't a good choice for the speed performance, the problem isn't the wi-fi router, probably is the server/PC share. [Try to create another share](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx) whit less file and try direct access.

However **SMB** isn't a good solution for this kind of app...

Comment: Thanks Paolo. I will try to cut down on the files in the target folder as there are rather too many. However, using exactly the same server and share but a different router, my access time drops from 21 seconds to less than four. The **only** difference is the router. All other hardware and software is identical. so why the 5x speed hit simply by changing the router?  You say SMB is not a good solution. What would you recommend?

Comment: Extra information: If I am fetching several files in succession, the 20 second delay only occurs on the first one. The remaining files come in at sub-one-second time.